# Simple group of order $3420$ has no element of order $171$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm stuck on an old algebra prelim problem which requires me to show that a simple group $G$ of order $3420= 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 19$ has no element of order $171= 3^2 \cdot 19$.

So far, since I know that $G$ has no nontrivial normal subgroup, it is clear that $n_{19}= 20, n_{5}= 6, n_{3} \in \{4, 19,76\}, n_{2} \in \{3,5,9,15,19,45,57,95,171,855\}$ via Sylow's Theorems. The next step would be to consider action of $G$ (by conjugation) on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ for some prime divisor $p$ of $3420$ (given as a hint). But which $p$(s) should I be using to follow this hint? I'd appreciate all the help I can get here, thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem, where did you find it?

Comment: In an old algebra prelim from almost 8 years ago.

Comment: from what university?

Comment: SUNY Albany. I'm trying to go over Sylow Theory.

Comment: Haven't actually solved it, but my guess is that said $p$ is a divisor of 171. By the Sylow theorems on the subgroup generated by your element (of order 171), you at least have that this $p$-Sylow will be normal in this subroup. P.S. I'm from Central NY as well :)

Comment: Can this somehow be proved by contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following lemma: Assume that $G$ is a simple group, $H\leq G$ and $|G:H|=k>1$. Then $G$ can be considered as a subgroup of $\mathbb S_k$.

For proof, consider the action $\phi:G\longrightarrow\mathrm{Sym}(\{aH\mid a\in G\})\cong \mathbb S_k$ defined with $\phi:g\mapsto \tau_g$, where $\tau_g:aH\mapsto gaH$. Th kernel $\ker(\phi)$ is trivial, since $\ker(\phi)\triangleleft G$, $G$ is simple, and also if $g\notin H$, then obviously $g\notin\ker(\phi)$, so $\ker(\phi)\neq G$. Therefore, $\phi$ is injective, so we can consider $G$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb S_k$.

Assume now that $|G|=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 19$ and $G$ is simple. Toward contradiction, assume that $a\in G$ is an element of order $3^2\cdot 19$. Then $|G:\langle a\rangle|= 20$, hence by lemma we can assume that $G\leq\mathbb S_{20}$. So, $a\in\mathbb S_{20}$ is an element of order $3^2\cdot 19$, which is not possible (you can easily see that by considering cycle decomposition of $a$).

Answer (score 4):

I should choose $p=3$ and remember that the Sylow Subgroups are permuted transitively by conjugation. If there are small numbers of subgroups you can get a non-trivial homomorphism to a small symmetric group, where the kernel is normal.

You might want to notice $p=19$ where $20$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Consider the structure of the supposed subgroup of order $171$ in the light of these facts.

---

Note that the case of $10$ subgroups of order $9$ has not been excluded (see comments) though not mentioned in the question. So this is not a full answer.

Comment: I seem to be going in circles with this problem. Still haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: @Libertron You might be able to show that the number of $3$-subgroups is not $4$ by the first observation. So the number is divisible by $19$. Since the action is transitive any $3$-subgroup is fixed by a group with order not divisible by $19$. Any element of order $19$ acts non-trivially and therefore (because it is prime) transitively on the $3$-subgroups. A subgroup of order $171$ contains a $3$-subgroup and an element of order $19$, hence every $3$-subgroup, and then ...

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. In the meantime, I will try to use the suggestions in your comment.

Comment: By the way, could $n_{3}=76$? I don't think that would work either.

Comment: @Libertron If there is an element of order $171$ there is a cyclic subgroup of order $171$ and this contains one subgroup of order $9$ (because of properties of cyclic groups). But the Sylow theorems, and deductions, tell us that it must contain $19$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Libertron $76$ is divisible by $19$

Comment: And the contradiction is…?

Comment: One is not equal to nineteen

Comment: How did you rule out the case $n_3=10$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't - I took the question on trust. Good spot.